# JQuery Id needs to be a variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax with Rails and JQuery.  Is there a way to get the id # at the beginning of the JQuery function to be a variable.  I have a checklist of checkboxes and want it so when the user checks on a checkbox the JQuery responds.
Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#item.id").is(':checked')) {  
     // how do I get the line above to work on every checkbox
      alert('checked!');
    } else {
      alert('not checked!');
    }
});
</script>



<%= link_to "Logout", root_path %>

<h1>Hello <%= @user.first_name%> <%= @user.last_name%></h1>

<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :to_do %>:
  <%= f.text_field :to_do %><br />
  <%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => @user.email%>


  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<% @items.each do |item|%>
    <%if item.email == @user.email%>
        <%= form_for @item do |f| %>
            <%= f.check_box :to_do, :id =>item.id, :value => item.id%> 
             //The line above gives the value to each checkbox
            <%= item.to_do%><br />
        <% end %>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Looks like what you want is an [event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/)

Comment: Try specifying with `class` as `$('.checkboxClass')` or element type as `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` instead of `id`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make    `if($("#item.id").is(':checked')) {`
as  `if($("#<%= @item.id %>").is(':checked')) {`